# PHP signup email-validate login script/class

Tags: php, registration

I am looking for a decent PHP script or class library to handle user sign-up/register, email-validation and login for a website. I've written this sorta thing before, but I'd rather use something more tested and robust. The handful of open-source offerings I have thus far come across are, in my view, not very good. I've also looked at [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/) and tho interesting is probably, for my needs, overkill. At this point I do not think I need a full CMS which would likely include such a facility.

Any pointers or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: provided link is broken, could you please fix it

Answer (score 1):

I used for my private projects Picora (http://picora.org/).
For more professional Work, you can use the ZEND-Framework (http://framework.zend.com/) components for this sort of things. This framework has a loose coupling to the core and can be easily used alone.